# How to make an object that has a another object as a parameter in JAVA

Tags: java

So I have 2 constructors

one for the object MyDate:

```
public MyDate(int month, int day, int year) {
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
    this.year = year;
```

and one for the object Person:

```
public Person(String name, MyDate dob) {
    this.name = name;
    this.dob = dob;
```

so how do I make a new Person object in my main method?

```
Person p1 = new Person(?????);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is:

```java
Person p1 = new Person("John", new MyDate(3, 8, 2022));
```

You can also instantiate a date first, separately, then pass the variable to the constructor for the `Person` object:

```java
MyDate endOfCovid = new MyDate(12, 25, 9999);
Person someGuy = new Person("John", endOfCovid);
```